# can i display a mini screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm  making an android test game. while playing game user can open a mini screen to write some things which user need  remember then close mini screen to keep playing game. how can i make this mini screen? 
i tried this method but it wasn't like method which i need.

```
public class CustomActivityTransitionActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void onClickNext(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create popwindow or using alertDialog and inflate any custom layout you need in it

Comment: could you give some tutorials about "using alertDialog and inflate any custom layout "?

Comment: this link custom the dialog in code 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

and it by using xml layout .

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

hope it useful for you